# Android Video (VideoView) no Audio when played

Tags: java, android, video

I tried playing a wav file using mediaplayer and i can clearly hear it but when i tried playing a video, no sound heard.

code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_layout);
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vdo);
        path = "android.resource://" +getPackageName() + "/raw/" +R.raw.video;
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
        videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    }
    public void doPlayVid(View v){
        Log.d("path",path);
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_video_play:
                videoView.start();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Why are you trying to play a .wav file using a VideoView. Shouldn't you be using an instance of MediaPlayer class?

Comment: @ParthMehta Sorry sir but i think you did not get what i said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set volume of media player. You can do by first setting  listener `videoView.setOnPreparedListener(preparedListener);`
and then you can in method `public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer m) {` of `preparedListener` set desired volume   `m.setVolume(0f, 0f);`

Example with inline listener:

```
videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.setVolume(0, 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am using a videoview to play the video

Comment: Sorry, but I am confused where is the problem, that  you use viedeoView is correct, you just need to set additional listener to him to get access to MediaPlayer to whom you can set volume

Comment: another suggestion: try other format  of video (MP3, MP4) maybe is just problem  with  codecs